# TFS aggregator not working as expected

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have tried to use TFS aggregator to simply total up a field..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AggregatorItems tfsServerUrl="[server Url]">

    <AggregatorItem operationType="Numeric" operation="Sum" linkType="Self" workItemType="Task">
        <TargetItem name="Total Work"/>
        <SourceItem name="Total Work"/>
        <SourceItem name="Completed Work"/>
    </AggregatorItem>

</AggregatorItems>
```

Now what I am wanting to do is have Total Work start at zero (so I have a default rule on that) And when someone enters(logs time) in completed work. It will simply +=.

but it seems to go crazy and when I refresh the page it is totalling many many times.

**Is it because I am using Total Work in the SourceItem as well as TargetItem**

Every time I refresh the task it gets bigger and bigger. I really only want it totalling when someone enters a value in the Completed Work.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, the way I made tfs aggregator to know the difference between a user change event and one that fired from an update by the aggregator was to re-run the aggregation and see if the value is the same.

If the aggregation sees a change is needed then it will update the work item.

since your target is a souce, that breaks.

Comment: So there is no way to do what I am looking for with your aggregator? Seems a simple enough requirement to me. Ah well, should just use JIRA :)

Comment: @John If JIRA fits your needs, then yes you should. However, throwing out TFS because a little plugin I wrote doesn't did not anticipate your requirements seems odd.

Comment: If you want to submit a pull request that looks at a comment rather than the aggregation I would merge it in.

Comment: I was joking on JIRA :) Is a much better tool. Have used it extensively. But I think I have figured out what I need to do using your aggregator and some TFS rules.